# delete a Excel Worksheet using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I try to delete excel worksheet named "sheet3" using vbscript,when script execute

> "test.vbs sheet3 test.xlsx"
>   the line “oBook.sheets("sheetname").Select ”，
>
> Report an error 800A0009,

how to solve this problem？

Script：(test.vbs)

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sheetname = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)    

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False    
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False    

oBook.sheets("sheetname").Select 
oBook.sheets("sheetname").Delete   

oBook.save
oBook.close

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True 
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True 

oExcel.Quit
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to `.Select` it? Just delete it.

Comment: You screenshot suggests the tab name is `"Sheet3"` but in your code you are trying to delete a tab with the name `"sheetname"`.

Comment: select the sheet to activate this sheet，write "sheetname" need to  script batch operation

Comment: Your script doesn't need to activate the sheet though. Activating and selecting is something us humans do. VB can just `Sheet("sheet3").Delete`. If you leave "sheetname" in there, in quotes, then that's the literal name of the sheet it's going to attempt to delete. You don't have a sheet named "sheetname" and so you get an error. Perhaps you mean to set a variable `sheetname = "sheet3"` and then delete that sheet `oBook.Sheets(sheetname).Delete` ?

Comment: yes,I want to  set a variable sheetname = "sheet3" and oBook.Sheets("sheet3").Delete,but always report error 800A0009

Comment: If you want to delete, specifically, a sheet named `sheet3` then it MUST appear in double quotes to be treated as a string literal "sheet3". So `oBook.Sheets("Sheet3").Delete` will work. If you don't include the doube quotes like `oBook.Sheets(Sheet3).Delete` then you are telling it that you want to delete the sheet that is named whatever is held in the VARIABLE `Sheet3`. You haven't defined that so you are essentially saying `oBookSheets("").Delete` which doesn't exist and so you error. I think you need to understand the difference between the string literal and the variable in VBScript.

Comment: How can the variable be assigned to my request?

Comment: First set a variable with the sheet name `myvariable = "Sheet3"` then use the variable to reference the worksheet: `oBook.Sheets(myvariable).Delete`.

Comment: set sheetname = "sheet3" , oBook.Sheets(sheetname).Delete,also the same?

Comment: That is close. The `set` doesn't belong though. We only use `set` when setting a variable that is holding an object (a workbook, a worksheet, and application, a class, etc).

Comment: I do not set the variable assignment directly, there is no error report, but ready to open the xlsx file can not open, the file is occupied, can not confirm the results

Comment: done！add On Error Resume Next ， tks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you don't have a sheet called "sheetname".  Try the following, and then you can use the sheet name you pass into the script as the first argument:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sheetname = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)    

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False    
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False    

oBook.sheets(sheetname).Delete   

oBook.save
oBook.close

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True 
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True 

oExcel.Quit
```